# Which checkboxes changed in a GridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I have a GridView where one column is a checkbox, like this

```
        <ecc:ExportableGridView ID="dgTrxAvailable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CellPadding="0" FixedColumns="" OnRowDataBound="dgTrxAvailable_OnRowDataBound"
            PageIndex="1" Width="100%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="N°" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCounter" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" CssClass="txtGrid t3 c3"
                            Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="3%" CssClass="t3" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TrX" Visible="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txt_id_transaccion" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" CssClass="txtGrid t3 c3"
                            Text='<%# Bind("id_transaccion") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" CssClass="t3" />
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Include">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Incluir" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="RuleDate" runat="server" Checked='<%#Eval("RuleDate") %>'/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="3%" CssClass="t3" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </ecc:ExportableGridView>
```

I want to know, of a group of n rows, which checkboxes changed, doesnt't matter if they were unchecked/checked.

What I tried is to add a class to the checkbox like this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
     $(this).addClass("Selected");
});
```

And ask in the backend:

```
protected void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow item in dgTrxAvailable.Rows)
    {
        if ((item.FindControl("RuleDate") as CheckBox).CssClass == "Selected")
        {
            //Logic here
        }
    }
}
```

but the value of `CssClass` is empty and I think there is a better solution to this without using magic strings, etc.

Any ideas?.